# customize approve.aspx office 365

Tags: office-365

I have several lists subject to content approval.
When I make a change to a list item it changes it's state to Pending. Then when a content approver approves my change I want to be able to change another item in a different list to reflect the approved change.

My plan is to change the approve.aspx page. 
To wire the click event on the OK button to a javascript function that changes the other list item upon approval using the CSOM.

Can I customize the approve.aspx in office 365?
Is there a better approach?

Comment: Since it doessn't seem possible (and it's prob a bad practice). I'm moving away from customization and creating a new Ribbon Button (via a feature) that calls my javascript function. That function uses the CSOM to getselecteditems and approve them.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701406/getting-sharepoint-selected-list-item-by-using-client-side-object-model-csom
http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-approvereject-content.html
http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-approvereject-multiple.html